# Creating Azure storage account hung Azure website

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-503

My Azure website was running perfectly until I've started creating a storage account under the same account (not linked to my website). The storage account has been stuck in the `Creating...` state for over 20 minutes, and since Azure started creating my storage account, my website has stopped responding.

On my website, I am getting 503 (Service unavailable) errors, timeouts, and standard ASP.NET server errors. I've tried restarting my website several times, and the errors persist even just after I restart the website and try to visit a static HTML landing page. The site hosts the API to our app, and now our app is also down. What can I do?

**UPDATE**: My Azure SQL database, linked to the website under the same Azure account, is online and is responding to queries without problem, if it helps.

**UPDATE 2**: I've tried changing the compute mode of my website from Free to Shared to see if does anything. It said The compute mode could not be saved, with no more error details. But I've refreshed the Azure management portal and my website appears to have changed to Shared compute mode and is in Running state. However, when I visit the website, I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your website in the West Europe datacenters? SQL, Compute and Storage are down as of this moment:

http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/support/service-dashboard/

Microsoft engineers are investigating the problems.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, it's on West Europe. Good to see that they are aware of the issue. Thanks